# What is the purpose of the single quotes in this regex expression?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string-literals

I've inherited some C# code with the following regular expression

```
Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$")
```

I understand this string except for the role of the single quotes. I've searched all over but can't seem to find an explanation. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try removing it to see what matches the expression and what not?

Comment: You can left only one of them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can tell, the expression is redundant.

It matches `a-z` or `A-Z`, or the `'` character, or anything between `'` and `'` (which of course is only the `'` character again, or any whitespace.

I've tested this using [RegexPal](http://www.regexpal.com/) and it doesn't appear to match anything but these characters.  Perhaps the sequence was generated by code, or it used to match a wider range of characters in an earlier version?

**UPDATE:** From your comments (matching a name), I'm gonna go ahead and guess the author thought (s)he was *escaping* a hyphen by putting it in quotes, and wasn't the most stellar software tester.  What they probably meant was:

```
Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z'\-\s]{1,40}$") //Escaped the hyphen
```

Which could also be written as:

```
Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z'\s-]{1,40}$") //Put the hyphen at the end where it's not ambiguous
```

Comment: So this doesn't match a hyphen? Given its purpose (to match a name) I'd expected the hyphen to be considered acceptable.

Comment: It would only match a hyphen if the hyphen were escaped (`\-`) or the hyphen was not ambiguous with a range (such as at the beginning or the end).  There's some other clever *theories* as to what the author meant below.

Answer (score 1):

The only way having the apostrophe / single quote three times makes sense is if the second and third instances are actually fancy curly single quotes such as ‘, ’, and ‛. If so a better (clearer) way to represent it would be to use the unicode escapes:

```
Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z'\u2018-\u201B\s]{1,40}$")
```

Incidentally some languages, such as PowerShell, explicitly allow these curly single quotes and treat them the same as the ASCII ' (0x27) character. From the PowerShell 2.0 Language Specification:

*single-quote-character:*

```
' (U+0027) 
Left single quotation mark (U+2018) 
Right single quotation mark (U+2019) 
Single low-9 quotation mark (U+201A) 
Single high-reversed-9 quotation mark (U+201B)
```

Comment: Although, then it would also match the characters that happen to be between the curly apostropes, and that doesn't seem to make much sense...

Comment: @Guffa it does make sense if the first one is \u2018 and the second is \u201B. See my updated answer.

Comment: I didn't realize that there were so many single quotes. They don't look any different. How can I tell?

Comment: @jmh_gr: Yes, that would make a bit of sense. You have to look up the character codes to understand what the expression does, so the more maintainable way would be to include the four characters separately instead of writing it as a range.

Answer (score 1):

As it is the three single quote characters are redundant. They represent the single quote character (#1) and the range of characters which both begins and ends at the single quote (#2 and #3 separated by a hyphen).

It looks like it is an error, the writer seems to have meant to include the hyphen character in the class by "escaping" it in single quotes.  Without escaping it the hyphen represents a character range, like in a-z and A-Z.

I'm guessing the original author meant [a-zA-Z'\-\s]

Answer (score 1):

The extra apostrophes are redundant, so it doesn't make much sense. One possibility is that the author tried to escape the dash to include it in the pattern, but the correct way to do that would be to use a backslash:

```
Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z'\-\s]{1,40}$")
```

(Using apostrophes around a literal is for example used in custom format strings, where the author might have picked it up.)