# What does ''-' mean in ^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$?

Tags: regex

I found a regex `^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$` from [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/validation) and does not understand the meaning of `''-'`. What does it mean?

## Edit

After reading the comments given to this question and the corresponding answer or deleted answer, now I know that this question must be deleted because this problem is about typo presented in the tutorial.

Comment: source of the pattern?

Comment: @hjpotter92: See the link given above.

Comment: `'-'` has no sense at all. It means `'`to `'`...Especially with the `'` before it it's even more useless!

Comment: No, it means ASCII code from `"` to `'`. Which might be quite confusing...

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden The question is valid. The OP asks about an unclear (and very probably useless) part in a regex he otherwise understands.

Comment: @Tomalak The linked (duplicate) question deals with exactly the same pattern https://stackoverflow.com/a/11854572/1190388

Comment: Goto Regex101.com, paste your regex there, it will give you a very nice explanation

Comment: @Artificial: Personally, I think the question is fine. The fact that it has been asked and answered before is not a problem. Your question even adds some new information: the source of the odd regex. The two answers that were deleted were completely irrelevant to your question, so that's entirely appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we leave out the other, well-understood parts of the character class, this remains: `[''-']`.

This construct has no use. It translates to *"the character `'` and the range from `'` to `'`"*, which is syntactically valid in regex but functionally equivalent to `[']`.

In the context of the annotated C# class property [on the MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/validation):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$")]
public string Genre { get; set; }
```

it's very likely simply a mistake by he tutorial author. The original intention is hard to guess. The following exactly the same thing.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z'\s]*$")]
public string Genre { get; set; }
```

Comment: Does this answer add anything new compared to the answer on the dup from 2012?

Comment: No, it doesn't. (Except that there's less speculation about other languages than C#). Posted the answer before I saw the duplicate comment.

Comment: I'm asking because it seems odd that you would hammer it open and then post a virtually identical answer, but I guess you missed that it was closed as a dup of **two** questions.

Comment: Yeah, it was a bit of a mix-up. I re-opened it because ot the first (the generic "what does this regex mean?") and got to work on the answer before I noticed the other one.